# How to execute multi AsyncTask Serial or Parallel?

Tags: android, android-asynctask

Hi, I have 2 AsynkTasks to get data from server and save it into SQLite.

When I click button this two methods will call:

```
btnGetICDatabase.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            requestAData("http://192.168.91.1/JSON-test/Table1.php");
            requestMData("http://192.168.91.1/JSON-test/Table2.php");
        }
    });

private void requestAData(String uri) {
    GetATDataTask getATDataTask = new GetATDataTask();
    getATDataTask.execute(uri);
}

private void requestMData(String uri) {
    GetMTDataTask getMTDataTask = new GetMTDataTask();
    getMTDataTask.execute(uri);
}
```

and this is AsyncTasks:

```
private class GetATDataTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {

        //Make ProgressBar Visible
        if (activityTasks.size() == 0) {
            pbLoading.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
        activityTasks.add(this);

    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

        if (httpManager.isWiFi(getApplicationContext())) {
            if (httpManager.isServerReachable(getApplicationContext(), ACTIVITY_TABLE_URL)) {
                String activityContent = HttpManager.getData(params[0]);
                dataSource.removeActivityRecords();
                return activityContent;
            } else {
                return null;
            }
        } else {
            return null;
        }

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

        if (result != null) {
            activityTableModelList = IronClubJSONParser.activityParsFeed(result);
            insertData.insertDataToAT(activityTableModelList);
        } else {
            Log.i(LOGTAG, "Activity Table couldn't Updated!");
        }
        //Make ProgressBar Invisible
        activityTasks.remove(this);
        if (activityTasks.size() == 0) {
            pbLoading.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }

    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(String... values) {

    }
}

private class GetMTDataTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {

        //Make ProgressBar Visible
        if (musclesTasks.size() == 0) {
            pbLoading.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
        musclesTasks.add(this);

    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

        if (httpManager.isWiFi(getApplicationContext())) {
            if (httpManager.isServerReachable(getApplicationContext(), MUSCLES_TABLE_URL)) {
                String musclesContent = HttpManager.getData(params[0]);
                dataSource.removeMusclesRecords();
                return musclesContent;
            } else {
                return null;
            }
        } else {
            return null;
        }

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

        if (result != null) {
            musclesTableModelList = IronClubJSONParser.musclesParsFeed(result);
            insertData.insertDataToMT(musclesTableModelList);
        } else {
            Log.i(LOGTAG, "Muscles Table couldn't Updated!");
        }
        //Make ProgressBar Invisible
        musclesTasks.remove(this);
        if (musclesTasks.size() == 0) {
            pbLoading.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }

    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(String... values) {

    }
}
```

When I click the button everything works fine, but I get this Info Logcat:

> I/Choreographer﹕ Skipped 39 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.

so:

1) Is there a better way to execute multiple AsynkTasks?

2) Witch execute method is better? Serial or Parallel?

3) If I have more than 10 AsynkTasks and execute all of them, will they work successfully?

thank you.

Comment: Probably the reason you are getting this is because you're doing a lot of calculations in onPostExecute ( because in asynTasks, onPostExecute  runs on UI thread)

Comment: How big is your result?

Comment: well first I check the URL for reachable then get the JSON  and save the whole content into SQLite database. @IspasClaudiu

Comment: Are you running in emulator or real device?

Comment: In emulator @Nag . I just want to know is this way to execute multiple AsyncTask is correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can execute multiple `AsyncTask` simultaniously there is no issue,

because every `AsyncTask` will run in a `Separate Worker Thread` so it don't effect on the Main Thread.

> I/Choreographer﹕ Skipped 39 frames! The application may be doing too
>   much work on its main thread.

Actually you are running on **emulator** so compare to real device it is too slow, so you will see the above messages in common.If you run on a **real device** you don't see that kind of messages.

Hope this will helps you.